# Why does the *net.UDPConn struct implement the net.Conn interface?

Tags: go

***net.UDPConn** is a packet-oriented protocol. So it makes sense for it to implement the *net.PacketConn* interface. However, it is confusing why it also implements the *net.Conn* interface, which is a connection-oriented protocol ( also implemented by ***net.TCPConn**) .

Comment: A udp socket can be "connected", and only a connected udp socket really satisfies a `net.Conn`.

Comment: (1/2) To add to what @JimB said, it stems back to a design choice (one that I think was pretty stupid) from the original Berkeley sockets API that has become the standard in Unix-like systems. Sockets, in this API, are stream-oriented data sources. Think a TCP connection or a file - unless the stream has been disconnected or closed, there's always a logical "next byte" to read, and it always makes sense to write a "next byte" to the stream. The problem is that UDP packets are not ordered, so UDP sockets don't fit this paradigm.

Comment: (2/2) The solution was to pretend that there are "UDP streams." In practice, a UDP stream is just a way of sending UDP packets without having to specify the source address/port or destination address/port because those were specified during setup. This acts a *little bit* like a normal TCP socket because all of the data is sent from the same sender and to the same receiver. But, since it's UDP, there's still no guarantee that data will be ordered properly, will not be dropped, will not be duplicated, etc.

Comment: @joshlf What's stupid about that? There are plenty of cases where it's acceptable for a stream to be lossy (live audio, video).

Comment: @joshlf Despite what you said... I was not sure what would happen if I write to the socket... and no receiver address is provided. Where will the UDP payload go to ? The standard documentation provides no such information. Or maybe I did not understand the UDP protocol enough.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - it's mostly just that it's unintuitive. Having run a college-level networking class, I can tell you that many people were confused by that behavior and it caused a lot of bugs for people who just didn't realize that that's how it behaved. I'm not saying it's necessarily wrong, just very unintuitive (which, in my book, is a negative in and of itself).

Comment: @felix.infinite - if I'm not mistaken, it should generate an error. But I'd just try it and see what happens. It's easy enough to test.